# My site in Spanish is not getting indexed by google

Tags: seo

My site in Spanish is not getting indexed by google well. Could anyone point out some locale specific measures I could take to make my site search engine friendly.

Regards,

Comment: Better ask this on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a sitemap and submit it to your Google Webmaster Tools account. Do have all your pages including your Spanish pages in that sitemap and that should do it.

Comment: I have been doing it but it doesnt appear in the  local google search. Is there a way I can tag it for Spanish content and make the site more SEO friendly by tweaking the code>

Comment: Well, besides the technical factors Google does have to determine that your content is index worthy.